# Data type mismatch on write, reading works fine

Tags: c#, ms-access, webforms, datasource

In an ASP.NET WebForms Project for .NET 3.5 the data is transferred to an Access database. The Site runs on an IIS 6 on Windows 2003 (English cersion).

In the ASPX file a AccessDataSource is used to read and write the data. Reading the data works fine, but writing dates fails. But writing works, if the date is provided as MM-dd-yyyy, but dd.mm.yyyy does not work. If the date is provided as dd.mm.yyy I get this error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

An code example leading to this error:

```
AccessDataSource myAds = new AccessDataSource("~/App_Data/mydb.mdb", "");
myAds.InsertCommand =
    "INSERT INTO [table1] " +
    "([Value], [Date]) VALUES ('data', DateValue('" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "'))";
myAds.Insert();
```

The Regional and Language Settings are set to German and therefore the correct Date Format.
In the Database date and time is stored in a DateTime field.

What do I have to cofigure to correct this, without changing hundrets of pages of legacy code?

Comment: this does nobody any good in regards to reading the message ... can you post the code, the schema and or tell us what the datatype is for the particular field is for the Date field .. is this a true datatime field , timestamp, varchar ...etc... please provide more useful information

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added code and Information regarding the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the regional settings of the App Pool user (on Windows 2003 it is "Network Service").

To do this I set the regional Settings not only for the administrator, but also for the default user account (see checkbox on the last tab in the "regional and language settings" dialog).

After a restart I exported the Content of `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International` from the default user data settings. Then I edited the .reg file and imported it for the Network Sercice user with the ID S-1-5-20 into `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Control Panel\International`.

After an IIS restart, everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If you are trying to insert the CurrentDateTime You can do like

```
 "INSERT INTO [table1] " +
"([Value], [Date]) VALUES ('data', Now())";
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I simply cannot change all the files in the project. That would be way to risky.

Answer (score 0):

That is only a dangerous workaround. Your core issue is that the SQL expression where you miss to convert the date value to a valid string expression, or to insert the date value from a function. You could have used DateValue but not with a German formatted string as parameter:

Here is how to to it:

```
myAds.InsertCommand =
    "INSERT INTO [table1] " +
    "([Value], [Date]) VALUES ('data', #" + DateTime.ToDay.ToString("yyyy'/'dd'/'MM") + "#)";
```

or:

```
myAds.InsertCommand =
    "INSERT INTO [table1] " +
    "([Value], [Date]) VALUES ('data', Date())";
```